# Multi message transformations in Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have Kafka-Connect which I need to integrate with a REST API which works best when called with a *single input multiple data* model.

Imagine the following:

**Source Topic** --> **REST Request** --> **REST Response** --> **Sink Topic**

**Kafka Source Topic**:

```
{"Foo":"Bar345354"}
{"Foo":"Bar454354"}
```

**REST Request**:

```
{
  "doWorkOn": {
    "message1Foo": "Bar345354",
    "message2Foo": "Bar454354",
    ...
  }
}
```

**REST Response**:

```
{
  "result": {
    "message1Foo": "Bar948474",
    "message2Foo": "Bar434343",
    ...
  }
}
```

**Kafka Sink Topic**:

```
{"Foo":"Bar948474"}
{"Foo":"Bar434343"}
```

So I would like to transform multiple Messages in a given timeframe.

The documentation for Kafka-Connect Transformations (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/index.html) indicates that it handles *SMT* or *single input single data* model. So I am searching for the *MMT* counterpart with Kafka-Connect.

So far I failed to find it. Could anyone point out what options there are?

Comment: So you're writing a sink connector, and you want to batch records from the source topic together, is that right?

Comment: Sink connector could work yes - but seems counterintuitive, since I want to produce the result of the REST Api to a Kafka Topic. I would have expected Transformations to be the solution but they do not seem to support MMT.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Kafka Connect isn't really the fit here. 
Kafka Connect connectors are for *either*:

- Source connector - pull data in from a system into Kafka
- Sink connector - push from Kafka to another system.

Neither of these fit the pattern you describe in your question. I think the solution lies in writing a stream processing application; taking data from a topic, doing something (external REST call), and writing it back to another Kafka topic.

For this the counterpart to Kafka Connect would be [Kafka Streams](https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-05-22&utm_term=rmoff-devx).

---

*Edit*: thinking about this some more, there is precedence for this pattern, in both Confluent Replicator and MirrorMaker 2 which both operate as Kafka Connect connectors, reading from one topic and writing to another.

Comment: That in turn would mean I lose Task sheduling infrastructure that is the basis of Kafka Connect, right? Or is there a way to tap into Worker infrastructure?

Comment: You're right, you would need to manage the task scheduling yourself. I've edited my answer to add in a point I've just thought of.

Comment: IIUC I would need to subclass `MirrorSourceConnector` and wire that up with `Herder`s and so forth. Seems possible but a lot more work than I had planned ;)